# how is it possible to use private api of qt i.e(private/qquicktextnode_p.h)?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qtquick2

I want to draw text in my `QSGNode`, so I want to use private API `QQuickTextNode` that can be included from `<private/qquicktextnode_p.h>`.

I want to know how can I configure my `qtcreator` to access these private APIs and others.

Comment: This isn't really related to Qt Creator much (it is just an IDE). You need to edit your project file(s). It would be helpful to know which build system (qmake, cmake, qbs are the likely options) you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `qmake` and want to add the private headers of the `foo` module you must add `QT += foo-private`, in this case:

```
QT += quick-private
```

Comment: thank you, could you add other answers for CMake and qbs ...?

Comment: @sayyedmohsenzahraee I still do not handle those tools, I am just starting my work with cmake for Qt so when I know I will update the answer, and qbs I still do not have it in view, in a future I will try to do it.

Comment: CMake: Use the Qt5Core_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS variable